# Problemas con el token

Tags: php

He estado probando utilizar Token de seguridad creados en forma aleatoria pero cuando escribo `$token = crypt($_POST['token']);`

En el navegador me sale:

> Notice: Undefined index: token in C:\xampp\htdocs\prueba\token.php on line 20

Éste es el código

```
<?php
session_start();
// Do Something
?>

<?PHP
$user_pass =  'Mi_Pasw0rd';
$salt = md5($user_pass);
$pasword_encriptado = crypt($user_pass, $salt);
echo $pasword_encriptado;
?>

<?PHP /*Página de inicio de sesión */
/* Si las credenciales de usuario se validan se abre una sesión y */
/* se agrega el token a la variable $_SESSION .*/

$token              =   crypt($_POST['token']);
$_SESSION["token"]  =   $token;
?>

<?PHP /*Página de inicio de sesión */
$pass = $_POST['password'];    
$passHash = password_hash($pass, PASSWORD_BCRYPT);
password_verify($pass, $passHash)
?>
```

¿Alguna idea de qué podría estar sucediendo?

Comment: Hola Edgar, Es recomendable siempre agregar el código que estás trabajando, para así poder ver lo que llevas y en base a eso ayudarte. Ahora de buenas a primeras, estás cargando la página `token.php` en el navegador de inmediato? o la estás entrando en ella luego de hacer un POST desde un form?

Comment: por favor edita tu pregunta agregando el codigo, es imposible leerlo en los comentarios

Comment: Cuando haces $token = crypt($_POST['token']);, estás intentando recuperar una variable pasada por POST, llamada token, ¿es cierto? ¿pasas dicha variable? lo digo porque el error es precisamente que la variable token no se está pasando por POST. Si nos pasas el formulario o ajax que llama al PHP te podremos ayudar.